# Perform a button click on key press on keyboard

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I want to click button in my app when i press a key on keyboard. It may be probably done by using If function. I'm not sure which variable equals to key press monitoring.

Comment: Perhaps you want to use a `KeyPress` or `KeyDown` event handler for a control or a form. Perhaps you want a shortcut, like `Ctrl+A`. Perhaps you'd be better with accelerator keys.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Using action lists

You might find the following example illuminating:

1. Create a new VCL application.
2. Drop a `TActionList` on the form.
3. Double-click the `TActionList` and create a new action. Set its `Name` to `aGreet`, its `ShortCut` to `F1`, and its `Caption` to `Greet!`.
4. Double-click the action in the list box to create its `OnExecute` handler.
5. Add the following code to the handler: `ShowMessage('Welcome!')`
6. Go back to the visual form editor and drop a `TButton` on the form.
7. Set its `Action` property to `aGreet`.
8. Run the application.

Now, as you can see, pressing F1 has the same effect as clicking the button.

Welcome to the wonderful world of action lists!

## Using only the accelerator

The above example assumes that you want to use a hotkey for your button. But you should also be aware of accelerator keys.

In Microsoft Windows, for decades, the norm is that all buttons, [except **OK** and **Cancel**](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20080508-00/?p=22403) have accelerator keys. For instance, the button's caption might be `&Save`, which means that the `S` is underlined and pressing `Alt+S` will "click" the button.

If this is all you need, you don't need to use actions (although actions are good for many other reasons) and you don't need to write a single line of code. Just add an ampersand character to the button's caption!

In a well-designed Win32 GUI, all buttons, except default (**OK**) and cancel (**Cancel**) buttons, should have such accesskeys. Keyboard users like myself get really annoyed when they need to tab 27 times or use the computer's pointing device.

## Other approaches

Of course, you can also create an `OnKeyDown` or `OnKeyPress` event handler for your form, see if the key is `VK_F1` (for example) or `S` with `Ctrl` being depressed (another example), and if so, invoke the same code as is invoked by the button. But this is likely a less than ideal approach, and it gets slightly more involved if the form has windowed child controls (hint: have a look at the `KeyPreview` property).

Just some examples:

```
procedure TForm1.FormKeyDown(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word;
  Shift: TShiftState);
begin

  case Key of
    VK_F1:                                                       // F1
      ShowMessage('You want help?');
    VK_F2:                                                       // F2
      ShowMessage('You want to rename something?');
  end;

  if (Key = Ord('S')) and (ssCtrl in Shift) then                 // Ctrl + S
    ShowMessage('Time to save?');

end;

procedure TForm1.FormKeyPress(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char);
begin
  case Key of
    ^A:                                                          // Ctrl + A
      ShowMessage('Select all!');
    'p':                                                         // P
      ShowMessage('A pause, perhaps?');
  end;
end;
```

Comment: I'd also set the action's `Hint`, maybe to `Greets you in a friendly manner.`. I like all my controls and menu items to have associated hint texts displayed in the status bar. Just remember to use the third-person singular simple present form of the verb.